# How can you get the piston extender block in your inventory?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

If you can use the `/setblock` command to place the piston extender, how do you get it in your inventory? I am playing on Xbox One.

Comment: Hi herobrine37, welcome to Arqade! Can you clarify your question to make more sense? I'm having trouble understanding your context and what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Answer (score 4):

The piston extension is a so-called "technical block", which you cannot have in your inventory. Other examples are flowing water, lit redstone lamp, melon and pumpkin stem, nether portal, fire, …

Here is the wiki page section about these: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block#Technical_blocks ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Block&oldid=1427839#Technical_blocks))

Disclaimer: My knowledge comes from the Java edition of Minecraft, but it's very likely similar in the console edition. The wiki does not mention any significant differences here.